# Area of intersection of polynomial inequalities.

Tags: integration, polynomials, approximation, area

Fix a point $(p_1, p_2) \in (0,1)^2$ and let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.

Consider now the following region

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D} = \{(x,y)\  :\  (x,y) \in (0,1)^2,\ 
n_1 x^i + n_2 y^i - (n_1 p_1^i + n_2 p_2^i) \leq \epsilon, \ \text{for all }i \in \mathbb{N}\}
\end{equation}

**Question 1**

> I would like to find the area of $\mathcal{D}$ as a function of $n_1, n_2, p_1, p_2, \epsilon$.

**Question 2**

> Let
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathcal{D}^* = \{(x,y)\  :\  (x,y) \in (0,1)^2,\ 
> n_1 x^{2^i} + n_2 y^{2^i} - (n_1 p_1^{2^i} + n_2 p_2^{2^i}) \leq \epsilon, \ \text{for all } i \in \mathbb{N}\}
> \end{equation}
>   Since the constraints change slower for higher values of $i$,
>   $\mathcal{D}^*$ seems to be a good approximation of $\mathcal{D}$.
>   Obviously $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{D^*}$. 
>   Is there a way to bound the difference
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathrm{Area}(\mathcal{D}^*) - \mathrm{Area}(\mathcal{D})\ ?
> \end{equation}

For example let $n_1 = 100,\ n_2 = 95,\ p_1 = 0.8,\ p_2 = 0.86,\ \epsilon = 0.6$.

In the following plot we see the first $20$ constraints.

[image: Constraints]

This is the region $\mathcal{D}$.

[image: Feasible Region]

These are the constraints of $\mathcal{D^*}$ for the previous example.

[image: Dstar-Constraints]

And this is $\mathcal{D^*}$.

[image: Dstar]

Comment: But not a function of $i$??

Comment: Couldn't you just integrate $$\int_{x=0}^{x=a} \left( \frac{n_1p_1^i+n_2p_2^i-n_1x^i+\epsilon}{n_2} \right)^{\frac{1}{i}}dx$$ where $a$ is from $(a,0)$?

Comment: $\mathcal{D}$ is the intersection of the inequalities for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Still, get $$\left[ \frac{n_1x^{i+1}}{in_2} \right]_{x=0}^{x=a}=\frac{n_1a^{i+1}}{in_2}$$ So oh I see hmm.

Comment: Seems to converge to square/rectangle, could subtract, $$A=\sum_i^{\infty}a_i$$ where $a_i$ is the cresent shaped sliver of area. To find it subtract area of $f(i)$ from $f(i+1)$, found by integrating from $x$ at intersection, to second intersection.

Comment: Or consider it as a parabola whose points are the points of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to outline a finite (finite I that while for example there are not necessarily nice solutions maybe to required points of intersection, they can be found with newton's method for example) steps to answer **question 1**.

First to define the boundary.

$n_1x^i+n_2y^i-(n_1p_1^i+n_2p_2^i)=\epsilon$

Solve for $y$.

$y=\left( \frac{\epsilon +n_1p_1^i+n_2p_2^i-n_1x^i}{n_2} \right)^{\frac{1}{i}}$

Now the intersection of $i$th and $i+1$th curve we plug in $y$ above to the $i+1$ equation.

$n_1x^{i+1}+n_2\left( \frac{\epsilon +n_1p_1^i+n_2p_2^i-n_1x^i}{n_2} \right)^{\frac{i+1}{i}}-(n_1p_1^{i+1}+n_2p_2^{i+1})=\epsilon$

Now using assumption, that at some point the intersections will be beyond the region and these will not effect the area. Substitute $x=0$.

$n_2\left( \frac{\epsilon +n_1p_1^i+n_2p_2^i}{n_2} \right)^{\frac{i+1}{i}}-(n_1p_1^{i+1}+n_2p_2^{i+1})=\epsilon$

This equation is to be solved yielding a function $I(n_1,n_2,p_1,p_2)=i_{\Bbb R}$ which gives the exponent yielding intersections at the boundary. All $i\in \Bbb N \le i_{\Bbb R}$ must be integrated.

The area is then

$\sum_{i=2}^{i\lt i_{\Bbb R}}\int_{a_i}^{b_i}\left(\frac{\epsilon+n_1p_1^i+n_2p_2^i-n_1x^i}{n_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{i}}dx$

Where $a_i,b_i$ are the two corresponding intersection points of the $i$th and $i+1$th curve and the $i+1$th and $i+2$th curve. The most inner section and two outer sections can be handled in a slightly ad hoc manner compared to above.